# Creating a Class Object within another Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a class object `Credentials` and perform the method `get_username_password` within the class object `Session`:

```
class Credentials:
    def __init__(
            self,
            username=None,
            password=None,
            client_id=None,
            client_secret=None):

        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

    def get_username_password(self):
        self.username = input("please enter your username: ")
        self.password = input("please enter your password: ")

class Session:
    def __init__(
            self):

        self.credentials = Credentials()
        self.credentials = self.credentials.get_username_password()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Credentials()
    a.get_username_password() 
    b = Session()
```

If I do it with `b`, `b.credentials` is a `None` type object.

Comment: Why do you immediately replace the `Credentials` object you assigned to `self.credentials` with the value returned from its `get_username_password` method (which *is indeed None*, as that method returns nothing)?

Comment: For `a`, `a.credentials = Credentials()` results in `a.username = None` etc., than `a.get_username_password` sets `a.username == input_str`. That works fine. For `b` it does not work. I would also expect `b.credentials.username == input_str`, but as I wrote above, `b.credentials' is a 'None' type object.

Comment: Please re-read the comment above: you assign `self.credentials` to the result of `get_username_password()`, which is `None`, as that method does not return anything. You just have to _call_ `self.credentials.get_username_password()`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. If I replace `self.credentials = self.credentials.get_username_password()` with just `self.credentials.get_username_password()` I get what I wanted. Thanks.Could you please explain the context with the @classmethod?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```py
class Credentials:
    def __init__(
            self,
            username=None,
            password=None,
            client_id=None,
            client_secret=None):

        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

    def get_username_password(self):
        self.username = input("please enter your username: ")
        self.password = input("please enter your password: ")

class Session:
    def __init__(
            self):
        self.credentials = Credentials()

    def get_username_password(self):
        self.credentials.get_username_password()
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work for me. Therefore I get the method `get_username_password` direct under `b` and also under `b.credentials`.

Answer (score 0):

`get_username_password` makes more sense as a class method that prompts the user for data, then passes the results to `__init__` as *required* arguments.

```
class Credentials:
    def __init__(
            self,
            username,
            password,
            client_id=None,
            client_secret=None):

        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

    @classmethod
    def from_user_input(cls):
        username = input("please enter your username: ")
        password = input("please enter your password: ")
        return cls(username, password)
```

It's debatable whether it should be a member of `Credentials` at all, as it's not something you should call from `Session.__init__` either.

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.credentials = c

    @classmethod
    def from_user_input(cls):
        c = Credentials.from_user_input()
        return cls(c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Credentials.from_user_input()
    b = Session(a)
    # b = Session.from_user_input()
```

As a general rule, keep I/O out of `__init__` methods as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi there Steffen. I hope you're doing well.**

The crux of your problem is that you are instantiating two separate **`Credentials`** objects. You instantiate **`a`** as a **`Credentials`** object and then you instantiate a **SEPARATE `Credentials`** object within the **`Session`** object.

**There are a few solutions to this problem that I am aware of.**

---

---

**1. Pass the credentials object into the Session object as an initializer argument.**

---

```py
class Credentials:
    def __init__(
            self,
            username=None,
            password=None,
            client_id=None,
            client_secret=None):

        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

    def get_username_password(self):
        if not self.username:
            self.username = input("please enter your username: ")
        if not self.password:
            self.password = input("please enter your password: ")

class Session:
    def __init__(
            self,
            credentials=None):
        if credentials:
            self.credentials = credentials
        else:
            self.credentials = Credentials()

        if not (credentials.username and credentials.password):
            self.credentials.get_username_password()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Credentials()
    b = Session(credentials=a)
```

---

**2. Create a singleton class out of **`Credentials`**. This would mean that you only have one object that represents the class as a whole. In other words wherever you instantiate it you will have access to the same ***single*** instance of **`Credentials`** properties. Here's a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_singleton.htm) if you'd like to investigate it further. I don't think this is what you're try to achieve though.**

---

**3. There may be other options as well. I'm not versed in all methods.**

---

**I hope this helps! Good luck!**

Answer (score 0):

`self.credentials = self.credentials.get_username_password()`
The problem here is that `self.credentials` is an object and you are calling the `get_username_password` method on this object but this method returns nothing so there's nothing that goes into `b.credentials` and therefore it becomes a `None` type object.

You can try something like this.

```
class Credentials:
    def __init__(
            self,
            username=None,
            password=None,
            client_id=None,
            client_secret=None):

        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

    def get_username_password(self):
        self.username = input("please enter your username: ")
        self.password = input("please enter your password: ")

class Session:
    def __init__(
            self):

        self.credentials = Credentials()
        # self.credentials = self.credentials.get_username_password()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Credentials()
    a.get_username_password() 
    b = Session()
    b.credentials.get_username_password()
```